# android compability problem

Tags: android

My current project is created for API Level 4 and I use custom implementation of the interface [Window.Callback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.Callback.html) there. When I'm running the project on higher API Levels I'm getting the error: *java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method not implemented.* That's because two extra methods added to this interface since API Level 5. **So any android interface can be modified in future API Levels and any application that uses modified interface will crash!?** How to solve this problem? I have two solutions, which is better?:

1. Use Proxy (this is not a problem but I don't want to complicate my code)
2. Built project under the latest API Level and indicate min-sdk=4 (but if new API Level is created I will have to rebuild my project again?!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try detecting the OS version and abstracting the classes you use through interfaces.  Another question covered this here: [Load class based on SDK version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989459/load-class-based-on-sdk-version)

This should allow you to selectively load the proper implementation based on which version of the OS the device currently running your app has loaded.

Comment: I have an identical problem, also regarding Window.Callback, and I do not see how this answer solves it. The Window.Callback interface is being called directly by classes from the OS. I do not have the ability to control what version of those classes is active. Of course, I could solve the immediate problem by adding the new methods to my implementation, but that will only last until Google decides to add some more in the future.